# Filter array items using forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, filter

I have one question about filter array in forEach. So I would like filter (bigger than in example) array using outside variable `filterKey`. I think that my function is correct by after filtered `newArr` is `undefined`. Could you explain what is incorrect?

```
var filterKey = 123456,
var array = [{ 
              ratings:{ users:[id: 123456]}, user: xyz
             },
             {
              ratings:{users:[id:9787389023]}, user:zyx
            }],
```

And my filter function

```
var newArr = array.forEach((ele) =>
                ele.ratings.users.filter((newEl) =>
                    newEl.id == filterKey))
```

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't return anything. You are probably looking for the actual [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Your `ele`ments in your example `array` do not have a `.rating.users` property that holds an array?!

Comment: Oh God, I forgot change array... sorry for messing

Comment: `id: 123456` is invalid syntax in an array literal. Did you mean to have a single object in each of the arrays?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: In this ratings.users in more than one id, and I would like filter all these id's with user id which is in variable like filtetKey

Answer (score 3):

Use array.filter method

```js
let array = [
{
  id: 123456, user: 'xyz'
},
{
  id:9787389023, user: 'zyx'
},
{
  id: 123456, user: 'che'
}
]

let newArray = array.filter((element) => element.id === 123456)
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .filter and you'll be able to filter your result set without using foreach since it'll loop across the array.

```js
var find = 123456;
var arr = [
  {
    id: 123456,
    user: 'john'
  },
  {
    id: 9787389023,
    user: 'leah'
  }
];

var results = arr.filter(function(node) {
  return node.id === find;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Nice :)